# In Java, how to close ThreadLocal resource when thread is finished

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-local

I have a third party Java library that provides a resource.

```
TheResource resource = TheResource.create()
```

Sometime later, when I'm done with the resource, I'm supposed to close the resource

```
resource.close()
```

According to the library documentation, the resource I create is a ThreadLocal variable. That means the resource is created per thread, and it sticks to the thread. My question is, is it possible to call the `close()` method automatically when the associated thread is finished? I think I can do it if the thread is my own custom thread because I can engage with the lifecycle of the thread. But my question is about those threads provided by the system.

For instance, in Android's [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) provides a thread for you. And I don't know how the thread is finished. I'm wondering if there's some kind of 'hook' mechanism in terms of threads' lifecycle so that I can close ThreadLocal resources of the threads.

Comment: I don't follow you.  You say the library creates a resource, but then the library docs say that _you_ must provide a `ThreadLocal`?  Maybe if you provided some code example or some direct quotes from the documentation...

Comment: I think understand what you are trying to do but also a pretty much difficult if not impossible without some weird java black magic. Even if you were able to listen for thread to finish you would have to call `ThreadLocal.remove()` in that dead thread context. Maybe `Object.finalize()` is the closest you can get but then it requires subclassing that context thread.

Answer (score 0):

The resource is likely not created statically but ThreadLocal so several threads may use their own resource independently.

Therefore *your* thread that calls `TheResource.create()` is that thread. It is your responsibility for a second and third call to `create` to do this on the same thread. And then `close` at that thread's end - on the same thread.

(Probably closing does not need to be done on the same thread.)

You could pack that in a class.

---

***Fpr instance:***

```
public class ResourceManager {

    private static final Set<TheResource> resources = new HashSet<>();

    public static TheResource create() {
        TheResource res = TheResource.create();
        // Not needced: Thread thread = Tread.currentThread();
        resources.add(res);
        return res;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        resources.forEach(TheResource::close);
    }
}
```

And in an application shut down:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { ResourceManager.shutDown(); }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer correctly. Let me put my question this way: Is there a way to clean up ThreadLocal variables in a custom way when a thread is finished given that the thread is provided by the system for you.

Comment: That's sample code for "how to create a memory leak in three easy steps". Cleaning up the resources only at the end independent of their actual lifetime is generally bad behaviour.

Comment: @Voo it indeed would be ideal to immediately clean up after usage. Not doing that can be for reasons of caching and so on, so the question seems a solid use-case; especially as _asking_ about the leackage..

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any available callback in the ThreadLocal mechanism. This leaves garbage collection, since all the objects in a dead thread's ThreadLocalMap will eventually get garbage collected. So you could override Object.finalize() to do your cleanup. Not ideal but...